# Unlink Function in Codeigniter Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to unlink image from my uploads directory but I am getting an error whenever I add dynamic image name, Here's my code

```
$filestring = APPPATH.'../uploads/'.$img_name;
unlink($filestring);
```

When I try like this it works

```
$filestring = APPPATH.'../uploads/img_1.jpg';
unlink($filestring);
```

Before APPPATH I use base_url here but it also gives an error like HTTP doesn't allow unlinking. Here's what I get from unlink($filestring)

> unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\mspares_dashboard\application../uploads/7.jpg): No such file or directory

I also tried this but it won't work.

```
$path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mspares_dashboard/"."uploads/".$img_name;
```

It gives me the same error.

> Message: unlink(C:/xampp/htdocs/mspares_dashboard/uploads/7.jpg): No such file or directory

Comment: And what are your thoughts on the shown `mspares_dashboard\application../uploads/7.jpg` vs. the real path/directory?

Comment: the path is correct but just i am getting like this \\\ in my path that creates an error.
When i try to give image name as a static then it works fine.

Comment: What does `getting like this \\\ in my path` refer to? "Getting it" where/how? And `application..` is probably not a real directory name (two dots in the name??)

Comment: brother .. is use for getting out of the current directory that is application

Comment: So, what you meant to do is `application\..\upload` then? `..` needs to be a path segment for that work, not just a suffix to the directory name.

Comment: sir i am saying when i use like this $filestring = APPPATH.'../uploads/img_1.jpg' it works fine for me, but when i do like this APPPATH.'../uploads/'.$img_name it not works.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\mspares_dashboard\application\ here's my complete path to controller, i have my uploads images in mspares_dashboard/uploads directory.

Comment: could you please tell me any other method to do unlink i have try this also C:/xampp/htdocs/mspares_dashboard/uploads/ but it won't works

Comment: Then presumably the second mistake is the lack of `img_` prefix in the `$img_name` var?

Comment: sir the $img_name is fine i also check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use file helper.
read file helper documentation : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: i think there's not any connection with the file helper.

Comment: You can use file helper for delete file , you should use folder with 1 file to delete ex :

`delete_files(APPATH.'../upload/{folder_user}')`

Comment: its delete file in folder without specific name , it's why you should create folder for specific image and delete the file.
Ex You need delete pict for user 

this is your folder
`/upload/userseven/7.jpg`

to delete file :
`delete_file(APPPATH."../upload/userseven/")`